# Checking account with no mail

Tags: banking

Is it possible to set up a checking account that creates no mail, or at least to redirect all mail to a different address?

I tried posting this question earlier and it was marked as off-topic, but I need to know this in order to escape from a financially abusive situation and I don't know where else to go. Hotlines couldn't help, friends couldn't help. I am at the end of my rope and I have nowhere else to go.

Comment: The problem won't be avoiding statements. Almost all want you to get them electronically.

The bigger issue is the avoiding of advertising. They always want you to get a credit card, or life insurance policy, or car loan from them. They will send the mail to your home address even if you are getting all statements electronically.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of three categories of mail you might get from a checking account:

1. **Providing you with a debit card** - This is avoidable by opening an account in-person and asking if they can provide you a debit card in the branch. You may have to ask around at multiple banks to find one that has this as an option. My local credit union (BECU) can print a debit card on-demand if needed, but this isn't universal.
2. **Statements** - This is easy to avoid if you make sure to enable paperless statements as soon as you open it.
3. **Advertisements** - This is probably the hardest to avoid. They're going to send you ads for their other services, like credit cards. Ask if you can set separate physical & mailing addresses, and make the mailing address a P.O. box instead of your residence (or wherever you're trying to avoid getting mail).

Answer (score 1):

Try again with hotlines and your local legal aid!

You'll easily find the help you really need.

Unfortunately it's basically all-but **impossible** to open a bank account with a "no mail here" policy - **really it is not possible**.

You'd be wasting your time chasing that.

Seek your free local legal aid!

Most people don't realize that if you **simply walk in to any lawyer's office**, and tell them you have no money but need advice, they will 100% find someone who will help you for free!  No problem at all.